# Why can't I import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*?

Tags: java, apache, import, pdfbox

I am writing a java program using the Apache PDFBox library. I've added the following .jar files to the java build path in Eclipse:

```
debugger-app-2.0.2
fontbox-2.0.2
pdfbox-2.0.2
pdfbox-app-2.0.2
pdfbox-debugger-2.0.2
pdfbox-tools-2.0.2
preflight-2.0.2
preflight-app-2.0.2
xmpbox-2.0.2
```

I'm not sure which ones are relevant so I added all the .jar files I could find at http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x.

Then, in my program, I try to import using the following:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;
```

The first three lines import but the 'util' line doesn't. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar contains `org.apache.pdfbox.util.*` package so this import should works fine. Check that all jars are correctly imported. You can check PDFBox [examples](http://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/examples.html) if error will raise again.

Comment: Thanks comrade! After reading your comment I delved into the pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar file and found out that the PDFTextStripper class that I wanted to import was actually in the 'text' package not the 'util' package. I had stumbled upon https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html and hadn't checked if it was still current. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Based on what you're importing, you only need the pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar for now. pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar has all the libraries you need for those imports.
2. Have you tried cleaning the workspace? It's often the case for missing imports. If cleaning doesn't work, maybe one of the solutions in this blog will: http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207